Прописать иначе
.full:hover {animation: full-0 .3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 1 normal forwards}
@keyframes full-0 {100% {transform: translate(-3%, -3%)}}

Возможно выполнить аналогичную анимацию, но не прописывая лишний раз keyframes?

что мешает просто transform прописать вместо animation?

Пробовал, можно пример, не силен в этом...

Можно попробовать сделать так
.full:hover {
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transform: translate(-3%, -3%);
}

